# Solve for $x$ from this quadrilateral without using law of cosines.

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Solve for $x$. I would be able to solve this with law of cosines (with a LOT of work!) but the students that this problem was presented are not familiar with law of cosines. Is there something I am missing? My approach would be to calculate the hypotenuse of the right triangle by using Pythagorean theorem. Therefore I would know everything needed to use law of cosines. If needed $y = (3x-4)\tan36°$. I think there might a simpler solution for this but what is it?
[image: The problem]

Answer (score 7):

In the diagram, take the right triangle and swap the position of the acute angles.  You then have a large right triangle as the complement of $36^{\circ}$ is the supplement of $126^{\circ}$.  Moreover, by arranging the side lengths as such, the $y$ variable is immediately eliminated.

Here's a diagram illustrating what we have now.

[image: Modified image]

Solving for $x$ using the Pythagorean theorem:

\begin{align}
(4x)^2+(3x-4)^2&=(5x-2)^2\\
16x^2+9x^2-24x+16&=25x^2-20x+4\\
-4x&=-12\\
x&=3
\end{align}

Therefore, $\boxed{x=3}$.

Comment: Nice solution! I didn't even think of the key step -- namely swapping the right triangle. It doesn't come naturally since one feels something essential has changed. But although one has changed the overall shape, one has not changed any lengths or angles in each part separately, and thus $x$ is preserved by the transformation. Again, nice observation!

Comment: PS. You could have simplified the algebraic work a tad by transposing $(3x-4)^2$ to RHS and factoring, since that gives $$(x+2)(x-3/4)=x^2,$$ which is more easily simplified.

Comment: Woah! Indeed a nice and elegant solution! I wouldn't have noticed this. Thanks!